# Can I set local storage item in parent window?

Tags: javascript

Initial page is on port `3001` (no server, CRA frontend) there one can open a pop-up window that points to `3000` port (Rails server).

I'm trying to set `localStorage` value in parent window (opener).

```
<<-HEREDOC
  window.opener.localStorage.setItem('authorization', 'Bearer #{@jwt_token}');
  window.close();
HEREDOC
```

But I'm getting

[image]

Do you think there's a way I can add storage value from popup to opener?

Comment: No. the best you can do is send the opener a message. The opener would then set it's own storage.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: It is the HTML5 Messaging API. Very straightforward

Comment: this is one form, but an implementation can be much easier if you don't want all this infrastructure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API/Using_channel_messaging

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks again, I'd accept that answer.

Comment: I've answered with a direct example from MDN.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, I just can't upvote (my rep. is too low for upvoting comments) or click on 'accept answer'. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: I'll help - I uprooted your question. It was well formed and led me directly to an answer. So thanks for that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: If you just search of the error message (and including the error message as text rather than an image would make that easier to search for), you will likely find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example from MDN that shows how to implement Cross Document Messaging. It is your use case as far as I can tell:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Example

Here is the relevant quote that explains why this alternative is important to consider:

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin
>   communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a
>   pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded
>   within it.

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to somewhere else. Answers should contain enough information to allow people to get the answer without going to another site. See [answer], especially the section titled "Provide context for links".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - thanks for the feedback, I've updated the response. The context for the alternative was provided (this is your use case), but I did not quote the page I linked to. So this should satisfy your concern. Please consider removing your downvote.